# ffmpeg output file dropping packets

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have an Amcrest RTSP camera that I am able to stream smooth RTSP video through the Amcrest web browser client and VLC (network connection is fast enough).

**I am able to write the RTSP stream to a file on my disk using ffmpeg**. I have experimented with different buffer sizes and frame rates, and file types (.avi .pg4), but no matter what I try, FFMPEG ends up dropping packets, and the video quality get pretty deformed.

Here's the output errors:
[image]

Here's the camera config:

[image: Here's the setup for the RTSP camera:]

Here's the command I am running to write the file

```
sudo ffmpeg -r 5 -i "rtsp://admin:my-password@192.168.0.186:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" \
-r 5 -b:v 1024k -maxrate 10000k -bufsize 10000k \
/home/trent/Dev/ffmpeg/test.mp4
```

Thanks, this is a first for me setting up a camera feed and I appreciate the help!

Comment: Just for testing play the rtsp stream with ffplay and Look for package Drops, vlc does buffering 1-2 seconds, Browser does not have rtsp maybe its web rtc or similar or rtsp over websocket. You can verify that with wireshark. In short rtp packages are not recv. in a sepecif timeout, thats every time a network related issue. Also you can try to use rtsp over TCP in case it is rtsp/rtp/udp

Comment: When I stream using ffplay it looks fine. That’s why I don’t think it’s a networking issue.  The webserver from the camera is also steaming well. 

The console output  indicate “Max Delay Reached” and then dropped packets. 

I wonder if I need to just use VLC?